# Using mac ports to install py26-gtk switches off my Mac

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, pygtk, ports

I'm trying to run `sudo port install py26-gtk` but my MacBook doesn't get further than `building gcc43`, while doing that it switches off without shutting down.

It is not overheating since I tried it again while my MacBook was sandwiched between two cold packs. The Mac was cool and the ventilation was not running. i.e. the Mac was not trying to cool itself when I used the cold packs.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing my Mac to switch off?

I have a Mac OS 10.6.3, python 2.6, mac ports 1.8.2.

Comment: What do you mean by switch off?  Did it just go to sleep during a long compile?  What does the system.log say (`/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`)?

Comment: The console is spammed by Chrome, I'm not sure which of the messages are caused by the switching off. By switch of I don't mean go to sleep, the behaviour is the same as when you take out the battery while it's running!

Comment: in kernel.log it says
kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: 3

This is bad. Looks like my laptop is broken: http://hritcu.wordpress.com/2007/02/22/my-laptop-broke/

Even though they replaced my motherboard once before : (

But why would it only happen when I try to build gcc43?

Anyway, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to you this means you have a hardware problem. Let's hope you still have apple care. I can't help but get the impression that apple hardware quality gets worse every year : (